# WSO2 Dashboard - Siddhi Data provider - Is it possible to call a rest API as the Store?

Tags: wso2, siddhi

Im trying a use case of calling an API and populate the graph in WSO2AD. Is this possible to use the Siddhi data provider for this or do I have to write a custom widget?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible. You have to write a custom widget.